# Where to put a pronunciation key?

Tags: formatting, memoir

In a recent [answer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/25847/13494), "pronunciation key" was mentioned.

I would like to provide a pronunciation key in my book.  It would be about half a page.  Where should I put it?  I'm concerned that if I put it at the end, people won't notice it, and will get ingrained in their mispronunciation of certain key names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't object to a half-page of pronounciation key at the front as part of the front matter. A six-page listing of characters, main houses, a glossary, etc. would be too much, but "Here's a quick rundown of how to say everything" before I start would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At the back. People will notice it if it's at the back, I'm sure they will. Normally, lists of characters are at the back of the book, lists of pronunciations are at the back, and general information is at the back or in an afterword.

You could have them at the front, if you pleased. It's really up to you. But, alas, I think it was user Mark Baker who said to me: 'why does it matter if the name is mispronounced?'.

Comment: I don't know....  It matters to me.  I want people to know how to pronounce the author's first name, for example.  (I'm the editor and annotator.)